# Translation of 放学

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm trying to translate the following text, but I'm not sure about the meaning of 放学.  Please let me know if my translation sounds right or if you have any suggestions!

美校は予備科を三度つとめた。洋画科にやっと入ったに三年目に二年やって放学となった。

"I tried to take the art school preparatory course three times. The third time, I finally got into the youga (western painting) course. I was repeating my second year, and I left school."

Comment: Does the original text say やっと入ったに? Isn't it やっと入った**の**に? And.. `I was repeating my second year` -> It's "I repeated my **3rd** year", no? cos it's **三年目に**二年やって

Answer (score 5):

放学 is an uncommon word, but according to Wikipedia, it's a synonym for 退学 (=expulsion from school). The article says 放学 is a even heavier type of punishment than 退学 in some schools, but 放学 seems to be used exactly in the same way as 退学 in your case.

Apparently this school makes it a rule to automatically expel students who were held back three times. He was already held back in 予備科 twice, and he could not advance to the fourth grade of 洋画科, which was his third time cumulatively.

> #### [退学](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%80%80%E5%AD%A6)
>
> 懲戒退学（ちょうかいたいがく）とは、犯罪・非行・過度の原級留置[2]（いわゆる「留年」）など、「本人に非のある」理由で、強制的に退学させる懲戒処分の一種であり、退学処分（たいがくしょぶん）、放校（ほうこう）、**放学**（ほうがく）などともいう。
>   懲戒退学は、校長（大学にあっては、学長の委任を受けた学部長を含む[3]）が行う。一般に「学校をやめさせられる」とはこのことを指す。放校・放学は「退学処分」の意味で用いられることも多いが、学校によっては退学処分よりも重いもので、「在校生であった事実」そのものが抹消されて、その後の復学も認められなくなることもある。